# Is there a way to save Excel document from Excel Javascript API?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I want to save an Excel document using the Excel javascript APIs. Is there any API, similar to Word's Document API in Excel that let's you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not yet, but is in our backlog to enable this.

Comment: Is there any other way we can detect if the file is unsaved and then save the file?

Comment: Again saving the Workbook is not possible today.  the plan is that the same method will save if needed.

Comment: If you only need to know if the file _has ever_ been saved, you can use `Document.getFilePropertiesAsync`. The result (`asyncResult.value.url`) will be empty if the document hasn't been saved. This won't tell you if there are any unsaved changes however.